# API Manager: Set API icon in Swagger 2.0 definition?

Tags: import, swagger, ibm-cloud, swagger-2.0

Is it possible to define an API icon in the Swagger 2.0 definition that will be shown on the app developers page?

Or is it at least possible to set an API icon in the API Manager UI?
I could not find anything related.

[image: API icon]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 4.0.1.0, The API Manager product itself does not support custom icons for APIs.

It does not really matter if you import the API through Swagger 2.0, or manually compose it in the UI, since the feature itself for custom API icons does not exist.  That said, we appreciate your feedback & will take it into account for future support!

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for icons in swagger.
As you have discovered you can't set an icon in the API Manager UI.

You can however set one in the APIm Advanced Developer Portal.
If you are a portal administrator or content author then you will see an Edit tab for the API, click that and you can upload an image file to be used as the API Icon.